# How to use the TelephonyManager in an Android app to get device information.?

Tags: java, android, flutter, security, exception

The error message java.lang.SecurityException: getMeidForSlot: The uid 11222 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers suggests that the application doesn't have the necessary permissions to access this particular device identifier (MEID) for the given UID (User ID) 11222. This restriction could be due to changes in Android permissions, where certain sensitive information access might require specific permissions that the app doesn't possess.

This function is proper working if android version is 10 or lass-then but i have use this code in all version so how to get device info or ICCID. i have follow all instruction in my app provide by [Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids).

I have add all required permission is add in my app and user are allow this permission.

I have use this function :

```
private Map<String, String> getSimInfo() {
    Map<String, String> simInfo = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        SubscriptionManager subsManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
        List<SubscriptionInfo> subsList = subsManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

        if (subsList != null) {
            for (SubscriptionInfo subsInfo : subsList) {
                String iccid = subsInfo.getIccId();
                if (iccid != null) {
                    simInfo.put("ICCID" + subsInfo.getSimSlotIndex(), iccid);
                }
            }
        }

        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        simInfo.put("AndroidID", androidId != null ? androidId : "N/A");
        simInfo.put("MEID","N/A");
        simInfo.put("IMEI","N/A");
        
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String meid = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
        simInfo.put("MEID", meid != null ? meid : "N/A");
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_GSM)) {
            try {
                String imei = telephonyManager.getImei();
                Log.d("IMEI DATA", imei);
                simInfo.put("IMEI", imei != null ? imei : "N/A");
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
             handleException("IMEI access not permitted", e);
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        handleException("IMEI access not permitted", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException("An error occurred", e);
    }
    return simInfo;
}
```

My App Permissions in AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_ICC_AUTH_WITH_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_DEVICE_CONFIG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

I have get this type of error :

```
E/SecurityException Error(29502): Security Exception: IMEI access not permitted
E/SecurityException Error(29502): java.lang.SecurityException: getMeidForSlot: The uid 11222 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3023)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3007)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2990)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2932)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getMeidForSlot(ITelephony.java:10794)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getMeid(TelephonyManager.java:2898)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getMeid(TelephonyManager.java:2855)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at com.example.sim_iccid_demo.MainActivity.getIccidList(MainActivity.kt:50)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at com.example.sim_iccid_demo.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:24)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at com.example.sim_iccid_demo.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$8Tzl3un6utopCfe_BwLm26cMOFo(Unknown Source:0)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at com.example.sim_iccid_demo.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:2)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
E/SecurityException Error(29502):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

I'm encountering a `java.lang.SecurityException: getMeidForSlot: The uid 11222 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers` error in my Java application. I'm working on sim and device info.
```

The code stack points out the failure occurring within the method getIccidList in the MainActivity class, specifically within the method getMeid or getMeidForSlot of the TelephonyManager class, which is responsible for handling telephony-related functionalities.

Comment: Regular apps don't have access to IMEI anymore. Just remove the code that depends on IMEI from your app or place it in an if block that is only executed on older Android versions.

Comment: yes, also i need to get icc id and imel number in my app.  but unfortunately it's not working so please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Look Here:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

They changed the Android IMEI and UUID Methods. You are supposed to use the Android ID which is a Tracker to get the Marketing Information. Even the MAC address is not supposed to be used. There is no definitive way to have a 1 to 1 connection because of Security Settings that can be made to make users identifiable.

Comment: ***<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
<!-- For MEID access, you may need this permission as well -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE_PRIVILEGED" />***

I have all ready add all permission